# PyInstaller: Как указать дополнительные библиотеки и медиа-файлы

Tags: python, pyinstaller

У меня есть такая структура файлов:

```
main_folder
   fodler lib1
   folder lib2
   ...
   folder lib 10

   folder images
   folder sounds

   lib11.py
   lib12.py
   ...
   lib15.py

   main.py
```

Как с помощью `pyinstaller` сделать из `main.py` `main.exe`, при этом собрав все нужные библиотеки (папки) и папки с медиа-файлами?

Заранее благодарю,
С уважением.

Comment: @Xybyyn, в папке с картинками вы тоже предлагаете мне прописать init ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог решить проблему.

Что бы добавить папки с медиа-файлами достаточно к команде прописать `--add-data Путь-до-папки/файла;Путь-до-папки/файла-в-приложении`. В моем случае это:

```
--add-data images;images --add-data sounds;sounds
```

Что бы добавлять свои библиотеки, нужно указать папку для поиска импортов с помощью `--paths Папка`. В моем случае это:

```
--paths .
```

Либо же можно просто загрузить свои библиотеки в `Python39/Lib/site-packages`, это мне тоже помогло.

Более подробно: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options